# Convert month number to month name with sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, dateadd

In my database the column "monthnumber" (varchar) indicates the month. (1 = january , 12 = december)
Now I need to echo the name of the month instead of the number.

I already found some examples and it seems that using `DateName( )` is the correct way to do this kind of stuff. But even with these examples, it's not working for me. Apparently I'm missing something but I can't figure out what...

**.htaccess file:**

```
RewriteRule ^example/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ test?year=$1&monthnumber=$2 [L,QSA]
```

**Html/php:**

```
<?php
    $year= $_GET['year'];
    $monthnumber= $_GET['monthnumber'];

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT DateName( month, DateAdd( month , 'monthnumber' , -1 ) ) AS 'monthname', monthnumber, year FROM `exampletable` WHERE year = :year AND monthnumber = :monthnumber";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(":year", $year);
    $stmt->bindParam(":monthnumber", $monthnumber);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
    ?>

    <?php echo strtolower($result['monthname']);?> <?php echo $result['year'];?>

    <?php
    }// end if
    else {
    echo '0 results';
    }// end else
    ?>
```

**Some row examples (year monthnumber)**

(2014 8), (2014 7), (2013 8), ...

When I try to open `example.com/2014/8`, it gives me "0 results" instead of "August 2014", while my old code (month displayed as number) works:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT monthnumber, year FROM `exampletable` WHERE year = :year AND monthnumber = :monthnumber";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DateName( month, DateAdd( month , 'monthnumber' , -1 ) ) AS monthname,
       monthnumber, year
FROM `exampletable`
WHERE year = :year AND monthnumber = :monthnumber
```

It is using functions from SQL Server, so I doubt this will work in MySQL.

You are better off just using a `case` statement:

```
select distinct (case when monthnumber = '1' then 'January'
                      when . . .
                      when monthnumber = '12' then 'December'
                 end) as monthname
from exampletable
where year = :year and monthnumber = :monthnumber;
```

You can also do this by constructing a date and using `monthname()`:

```
select distinct monthname(date(concat_ws('-', year, monthnumber, '01'))) as monthname
from exampletable
where year = :year and monthnumber = :monthnumber;
```

Note:  you should only use single quotes for date and string constants.  Never use single quotes around column names, it will just lead to problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I used monthname() and it works fine. Just one more question: does that code support other languages too? Let's say that I'd like to display the name of the month in French or German? Or do I need to use the `case` statement then?

Comment: @Stan . . . Use a `case` statement.  It should return the value in the language of the database, and you may not have much control over that.

Answer (score 0):

> In MySql just use following statement to convert number to month (working example)

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(id,'%m')) as nameofmonth FROM `user`
```